# What are the eigenvalues of this infinite dimensional matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

This matrix appears again and again in quantum many body theory. I don't know how to find its eigenvalues.

Imagine a "matrix" M whose components are: M_{x,x'} = u(x)G(x-x') where u
and G are complex valued functions of integers x and x'. M is an
infinite dimensional matrix. Please tell me what are its eigenvalues for a
general u and G (assume any regularity conditions that you desire).

Comment: Don't you think, that is a bit too general a specification to result in specific eigenvalues?

Comment: The eigenvalues are function(al)s of u and G